# How do you add more than one UIBarButton on UINavigationItem.rightBarButtonItem (or leftBarButtonItem)?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

I have tried this approach/hack:
http://blog.blackwhale.at/2009/06/uibuttons-in-uinavigationbar/

The problem is this leaves a faint seam. I tried setting the background image of the nested toolbar to an image I captured of what it should be. That didn't work. The image was not applied. I have also tried using a nested UINavigationBar and that didn't seem to work.

I have seen this done in several iPhone apps. Does anyone know how?

[EDIT] I want the buttons to look like normal UIBarButtonItems and be able to use system styles like UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd, UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh. The link I provided does this except you can see a faint seam because it is a UIToolbar nested in the navigationbar..

Please don't mention this breaking the Human Interface Guidelines. (We know).

I appreciate you contributing your hacks... thats the only way to do this!

Comment: The link you mentioned is down :-(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get rid of the background ('seam') of a UIToolbar, create a subclass of UIToolbar and override the (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect method. Leave that blank and your UIToolbar will no longer have a background.

Just used this in my own project and worked great. Found this in the comments of: http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html

Comment: FYI, iOS 5.0 supports multiple nav bar buttons.  See the answer I posted below.  However, if you need to deploy for older versions of the OS then you will still need to use the technique described in this answer.

Answer (score 36):

iOS 5.0 now supports multiple buttons.  See the iOS documentation for UINavigationItem.  Specifically, the following:

Properties:

```
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *leftBarButtonItems;
@property(nonatomic, copy) NSArray *rightBarButtonItems;
@property BOOL leftItemsSupplementBackButton;
```

Methods:

```
- (void)setLeftBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)items animated:(BOOL)animated;
```

Answer (score 18):

I posted [code to add two buttons to the right of the navigationBar](http://www.mattdipasquale.com/node/48). You can set `barStyle = -1` instead of subclassing `UIToolbar`.

Comment: Your link is broken :(

Comment: It's still up on google cache: http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:-cVMtn4dPKcJ:www.mattdipasquale.com/blog/2010/11/02/how-to-add-multiple-uibarbuttonitems-to-uinavigationbar/+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk

Answer (score 3):

```
UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, myWidth, myHeight)];
// make UIView customView1... (UILabel, UIButton, etc.) with desired frame and settings
[parentView addSubview:customView1];
[customView1 release];
// make UIView customView2... (UILabel, UIButton, etc.) with desired frame and settings
[parentView addSubview:customView2];
[customView2 release];
UIBarButtonItem *customBarButtomItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:parentView];
[parentView release];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = customBarButtomItem;
[customBarButtomItem release];
```

Comment: I want the buttons to look like normal UIBarButtonItems and be able to use system styles like UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd, UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh. The link I provided does this except you can see a faint seam because it is a UIToolbar nested in the navigationbar.

Comment: I tried this before and the button looks different. But you can take a screenshot image of the look you want and use that in the button.

Answer (score 2):

see uicatalogue example available at apple's site for free...they used uisegmented control to show three buttons in place of right bar button on navigaion bar...

Comment: Sorry. I'm not looking for a segment control. I want the standard buttons like + (add button), Edit, refresh icon and so on.

Comment: you can add a custom view with your desired buttons...search google for the custom view code..you'll be able to get it

Comment: there are many tutorial on net to do this.if you've tried post your code

Comment: I looked into it again and I think this way is actually pretty good. The only problem is getting the standard icons if you need them. The segment control buttons look like normal navigation buttons if you do this.

Comment: BTW I didn't see the example you were talking about. I have a different version of the UICatalog project I guess. I did see it in the Interface Builder. You can drop the segment control onto the naviation bar left/right/center.

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment but in addition to @iworkinprogress I had to set the UIToolbar background color to clear:

```
    [toolbar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```

This was also found in the comments of http://osmorphis.blogspot.com/2009/05/multiple-buttons-on-navigation-bar.html.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 4.x the clearColor seems to have no effect on the UIToolbar, whereas overriding its drawRect: did.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a helper function I'm using all over my project. Basically it checks if there is already a button on the bar and either add the new one or merge it with existing buttons. So you can call the function just once or multiple times:

```
+ (void)AddButtonToBar:(UIViewController *)controller withImage:(NSString *)imageName withAction:(SEL)action withFrame:(CGRect) frame{
    UIButton *newButton =[[UIButton alloc] init];
    [newButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:imageName] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    newButton.frame = frame;
    [newButton addTarget:controller action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    if ([[controller.navigationItem rightBarButtonItems] count] == 0)
        [controller.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:newButton]];
    else {
        NSMutableArray *existingButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[controller.navigationItem rightBarButtonItems]];
        [existingButtons addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:newButton]];
        [controller.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItems:(NSArray *)existingButtons];
    }
}
```

Call it from the view controller:

```
[Helper AddButtonToBar:self withImage:@"imageName.png" withAction:@selector(myAction) withFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 24, 24)];
```