# How to add multiple buttons iOS > 4?

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem

How to add multiple buttons in navigation bar for iOS > 4?

For iOS > 5, I know there is property for that, but how to support it also for iOS 4?

Have searched a solution and a there is a post suggests using a segmented control, but I want my 2 buttons look separated.

Can I achieve that?

Comment: Try `[navigationBar addSubview:customButton];` you cant add `UIBarButtonItem` this way, probably you need to use segmentControl with only one segment or custom button.

Comment: Look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414510/how-do-you-add-more-than-one-uibarbutton-on-uinavigationitem-rightbarbuttonitem) SO question, it might help you.

Comment: @AnkurArya yes yours is the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since AnkurArya link in comment is gone, I post my solution here:

```
  self.firstButton = 
      [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 6, 36, 32)] autorelease];
  self.secondButton = 
      [[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(38, 6, 36, 32)] autorelease];

  UIView *rightView = 
      [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 75, 44)] autorelease];
  rightView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  [rightView addSubview:firstButton_];
  [rightView addSubview:secondButton_];
  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = 
      [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightView] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some custom buttons and add on the navigation bar as `[navigationBar addSubview:customButton];` you cant add `UIBarButtonItem` this way since it is not a `UIView`, probably you need to use segmentControl with only one segment or a custom `UIButton`.